# Good class name needed for wrapper class that contains initialisation and configuration data for other class

Tags: naming-conventions

Basically I'm just looking for a word that means something like "initialisation and configuration data".

(It should not be "configuration" because that would cause confusion with one of the parts of the whole).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FooInfo`

[ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) being an example.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<OtherClass>Setup
```

Or:

```
<OtherClass>Settings
```